# How do I copy a link from Google search results to clipboard on Android Chrome?

Tags: chrome-for-android, google-search, copy-paste

On Chrome for Android, when I do a Google search and some of the results are non-HTML documents, like PDFs. How do I copy a clean URL to the clipboard?

Example search: https://www.google.com/search?q=sodium+polyacrylate+msds

[image: screen shot]

Tapping the result just opens the document for viewing, so there is no address bar to copy the URL from:

[image: screen shot]

Long-press then copy link gets Google's indirect links instead, like:

```
https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.hmsmedical.com/images/44-oc%2520msds.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwj2msqg3tDOAhXKox4KHdRoAMYQFggeMAA&usg=AFQjCNGEptV-_ZvoTUjoL68GOAAyrYtP0A&sig2=4XRpaDAeBjkQZlxEUXWH9A
```

Manually deleting all that other stuff then hand decoding the URL parameter is a massive pain on a phone.

How do I just copy the link?

Answer (score 3):

You will need to look for a script or add on that takes care of it.

MakeUseOf has a link for a script to use with desktop firefox and chrome, its possible the script has an Android Chrome variant, or the script is fine for android and that its the engine that you need, to be specific to Android's Chrome browser.

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/copy-crapfree-urls-googles-search-results/

eg: look for scriptish or greasemonkey on android, also note since the script provided at MakeUseOf is outside the store, you will most likely have to do the manual-add they mention.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks I will look into this and post back with the results. You'd think Google wouldnt make this difficult for their own search results in their own browser on their own os.

Comment: Actually, the link exists for google to track you. When you copy, it may simply imply you want to paste it in another tab, and google doesn't want to miss a single opportunity  to track you.

Comment: I looked into this; unfortunately, all the scriptable browsers I found (like the Tampermonkey browser) have too many other shortcomings to make it worth it. But they do work. I'm going to continue to investigate other options first before accepting / posting an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is really an old thread but none of the options here worked for me.   What did work is to drag the link to an input field.   For example, while visiting the page if you first clear out the URL address field in the browser, then tap and hold on the desired link then drag it up to the address field and release there it will paste the PDF's address there, then you can highlight and copy it in the normal way you would for an address (depending on the browser you're using)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the google search bar, open chrome for google and type what you want to search for in the address field.  Now when you click and hold on the link you'll get the menu that lets tou copy the link address

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using slow internet connection because I searched the link you provided on my android google chrome and when I long press the search results I got actual link not google redirect. Actually when we have a slow connection so the google automatically compress the results upto 80% so we not go through original links instead it redirects to googleweblight
[image]

Comment: @Jason C check out my answer

Comment: I simply copied the url you   posted in question and pasted it in   chrome

Comment: you may try to update your google chrome or try to reset to default setting

Comment: does your problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative option that should work on any browser, I wrote a little web page to clean up links copied from Google search results: https://urlclean.com